# Apache case insensitive using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How would I make Apache case insensitive using .htaccess?

Issue: If I try to access same page using capitalized string instead of lower-case, it is not working as expected.

I have read other posts and still cant get it to work? if someone can help it would be much appreciated! 
My `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
AddType text/x-component .htc
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
    CheckSpelling on
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the module (`mod_speling`) before it will work...

Assuming you're using Ubuntu, run this from the command prompt:

```
sudo a2enmod speling
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: thanks for your response! I am unable to access command prompt as I am on shared hosting with godaddy. is there another way i can access command prompt and enable mod_spelling ?